# Java convert for loop into lambda expression

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8

I want to convert the below code into lamda expession, especially the FOR LOOP marked in bold, starting from 1st index and skipping the next index[i=i+2]

```
public static List<Integer>  integerArrayList = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

  Thread oddThread8 = new Thread(() -> {
  List<Integer> integerArrayList = ReadList8Refctor.getIntegerList();
  int listSize = integerArrayList.size();

  for(int i=1; i<listSize; i=i+2) {
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+integerArrayList.get(i));
     }

}, "ODD");
```

I get perfect output, help me to refactor the FOR LOOP, Thanks in Advance

```
ODD - 1
ODD - 3
ODD - 5
EVEN - 0
EVEN - 2
EVEN - 4
EVEN - 6
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Which jdk are you using?

Comment: I was able to complete it, thanks for all  /*Code Starts here */ List<Integer> oddList = ReadList8Refctor.getIntegerList().stream().filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
            oddList.stream().forEach((value) -> {System.out.println(value);

Comment: 1) get a STREAM of filter with the condition (i -> i % 2 != 0). 2) Do a forEach on the stream

Comment: @user2488681 `filter` on the index and the element are two different things.. you `for` loop code iterating odd indexes, while the stream code would filter values that are odd. It so happens to coincide with the provided input that your result might be same.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java-9 you can use :-

```
 IntStream.iterate(1,i -> i < listSize ,i ->i+2).forEach(i -> Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+integerArrayList.get(i));
```

On java-8 :-

```
 IntStream.range(1,listSize).filter(value -> value%2!=0).forEach(i -> Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+integerArrayList.get(i));
```

Comment: `forEach` being a void terminal operation, you might want to perform a task there or else `mapToObj` and `collect` to use it later.

Answer (score 0):

On java-8 you can do it by using `IntStream.range()`

```
IntStream.range(1, listSize)
         .filter(i->i%2!=0)
         .forEach(i->System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+integerArrayList.get(i)));
```

From java-9 you can limit the result in `iterate` itself

```
IntStream.iterate(1, i->i<listSize,i->i+2)
         .forEach(i->System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+integerArrayList.get(i)));
```

Or by using `stream.iterate` from java-9

```
Stream.iterate(1, i->i<listSize,i->i+2)
       .forEach(i->System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+integerArrayList.get(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with foreach:

```
    integerArrayList.stream().forEach(e->{
        if(e%2 != 0){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+integerArrayList.get(e));
        }
    });
```